# Connected to internet but can't browse after trying to remove Covenant Eyes

Tags: macos, networking, internet

I recently got a MacBook Pro. It connects to ethernet\wifi and has internet but when I open Safari or Firefox, nothing happens. I get a timeout for all websites.

I had [Covenant Eyes](http://www.covenanteyes.com/) on my Mac before and tried to remove it.

My friends who work with computers have tried everything (`ping`, `nslookup` etc).

- Network diagnostics show no problems
- I can see I'm connected through `ifconfig` because I get an IP.
- I also get a response pinging `www.google.gr`.
- There are no proxies set in my Network preferences.

Any ideas?

Comment: yes it worked until  i made a new account. nothing else connected than the mac . When i made a new account it worked , i left it to sleep for an hour and after i got it back on it didn't work

Comment: Have you looked at this page: http://www.covenanteyes.com/support-articles/how-do-i-uninstall-covenant-eyes/ ?

Comment: the thing is that I don't have the codes I need to uninstall covenant eyes because someone gave me the mac without me knowing that it contains passwords and now that person is in Australia and I'm in Greece.... :\

Comment: I do not know how that software works but if this (http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=15798) doesn't work, you may need to call their support.

Comment: it doesn't work, I'll probably call support. however, do you know how to get mac os 10.6.4 for reinstall cause I don't have original dvd?

Comment: Have you tried requesting an uninstall code from Covenant Eyes?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you've removed it completely. The current version of Covenant Eyes for Mac (2.8.3) leaves the following files:

- /usr/libexec/CvntDaemon
- /Library/LaunchAgents/com.Cvnt.start.plist
- /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.Cvnt.daemon.plist
- /private/var/db/receipts/com.Cvnt.CovenantEyes.bom
- /private/var/db/receipts/com.Cvnt.CovenantEyes.plist
- /Library/Extensions/Cvnt.kext
- /Library/Extensions/CvntDriver.kext
- /System/Library/Extensions/Cvnt.kext
- /System/Library/Extensions/CvntDriver.kext
- /Applications/Covenant Eyes.app
- /Applications/Utilities/Uninstall Covenant Eyes.app
- /private/var/.ce/*

Make sure you've removed ALL of them. The lists I've found for removal did not include the files at /Library/Extensions/Cvnt* which means that while it would ping, trace and respond to web services, it would still fail to connect to websites.

You'll need to unlock the kext files with the following before you can delete them:

```
sudo -s
chflags nouchg /Library/Extensions/Cvnt.kext
chflags nouchg /Library/Extensions/CvntDriver.kext
chflags nouchg /System/Library/Extensions/Cvnt.kext
chflags nouchg /System/Library/Extensions/CvntDriver.kext
```

After removing those files you may also have browser extensions installed that need to be removed through the browser itself.